# How to make a image visible based on a value from a combo box/Text Box in a Access Report?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have the report mostly working and setup the way I want it but I'm running into a issue where there are two signatures used on the report.. I want the report to show only the signature selected based on a combo box value? The Value is coming into the report but the code I did in VBA in the Event of On Open isn't making my signatures visible... what am I doing wrong? This is what I'm using... My combobox on the report is called cboSelectSignatureToUse and the images in the report is called imgGailSig and imgDanSig. Heres the code I tried with no luck.

```
If Me.cboSelectSignatureToUse.Value = "Dan" Then
Me.imgDanSig.Visible = True
Me.ImgGailSig.Visible = False
Else
Me.ImgGailSig.Visible = True
Me.imgDanSig.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: What is the RowSource of this combobox? Is combobox value really a string like "Dan" or is it an ID?

Comment: Reports aren't dynamic like forms are. The combo box should probably be on the form that opens the report, so it can be evaluated on Report load.

Answer (score 0):

Can use OnLoad event if report is filtered to a single record.
If multiple records are pulled, use OnFormat or OnPrint event of section that contains the image control.

Consider:

```
Me.ImgGailSig.Visible = Me.cboSelectSignatureToUse.Value = "Gail"
Me.imgDanSig.Visible = Me.cboSelectSignatureToUse.Value = "Dan"
```